# Is it possible to write loop in Scala Console?

Tags: scala

I try to test this in Scala Console (I mean console not script file):

```
while i < 10 {print(i) i += 1}
```

It doesn't work. I tried multiple lines it doesn't seem to either.

Am I obliged to use a script file just to test a simple loop ?

Answer (score 10):

Yes it's possible. You have some syntax errors though:

```
var i = 0
while (i < 10) { println(i); i += 1 }
```

Or on multiple lines:

```
var i = 0
while (i < 10) {
  println(i)
  i += 1
}
```

Comment: Of course for the same effect there's: for( i <- 0 until 10 ) { println( i ); }, the "while" way of doing it seems unusual in Scala.

Comment: Or the even more succinct "0 until 10 foreach println"

Answer (score 6):

As usual, there is more than one way to do this:

```
// join values beforehand and print the string in one go
println(0 to 9 mkString("\n"))
// using foreach
(0 to 9).foreach(println)
// using for
for(i <- 0 to 9) println(i)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
scala> while i < 10 {print(i) i += 1}
<console>:1: error: '(' expected but identifier found.
       while i < 10 {print(i) i += 1}
             ^
```

As indicated by the error message, a while must be followed by an "(", as the condition it tests for must be enclosed inside parenthesis. The same thing holds true for "if" and "for", by the way.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is this:

```
var i = 0; while (i < 10) { print(i); i += 1 };
```

Answer (score 1):

On the other hand, Scala encourages you to not use a mutable variable and while + condition

If you want to print the numbers from 0 to 9, use a [sequence comprehension](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/111) :

```
for (var <- range ) doSomethingWith (var)
```

In your case will be:

```
for (i <- 0 to 9) print (i)
```

(yes, the example looks pretty silly, but it helps to transition to a more "Scalaish" code)